# How to put a hole in a wall (VFX)

Tags: video, video-editor, software, visual-effects

This is a really basic VFX question. I just downloaded Blackmagic DaVinci Resolve (with fusion) and I was interested in trying out VFX. I thought it would be a cool idea to try to put a hole in the wall of my house in a moving handheld shot. I just don't really have any idea how.

I'm not asking for specific buttons to press in the software, **I just want to know a general order of events to achieve that goal.** (Like what tracking to use, and how to display the whole in the wall in a spatially accurate way, etc...) It's a pretty basic project, I just need somewhere to start off. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call it a basic project. Making the geometry of the room behind the hole work with the camera movement is going to either involve creating it in a 3D animation package and rendering realistically, or using motion control to match the movement of the foreground. It would be easier to add a wall with a hole where no wall exists.

Comment: Yeah, this is an involved effect. It's basically animation, a specialized video production skill.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve has a pretty solid tracking system built-in. I would recommend you track your footage first and make sure your trackers really stick to the wall. From there, you can go many ways.

The cheap and easy way is to just take a hole.png and attach it to the trackers, so it sticks to the wall. This might look bad though when moving around the wall, since the geometry of the .png will not change.

The more advanced option would be to export the tracked data (I would recommend pftrack for that) and importing the tracked camera into any 3d-software you like (such as cinema 4d, modo, 3dsmax, etc). There, you can create a 3D-Model of said hole by grabbing the texture from the original footage on the edges and then just blend into concrete/brick-textures you can find online for the parts that penetrate the wall. By now beveling inwards and shaping the mesh a bit, you should quickly come to a promising result.

For the next step, it is very important that you study the light from your scene and try to recreate it in 3D as accurately as possible. Lighting, the angle and color of it makes or brakes your 3D-composition.

When you're done with that, you can render out a sequence as long as your original clip from the perspective of your tracked camera. To get ultra-accurate results, you can also match the focal length and distance as well.

If you now take your rendered 3D-hole and lay it on top of your original footage (plus some blending and color grading to make it sit right in the footage) it should stick perfectly to your wall.

Hope I was able to help, if you have further questions please ask. Have a wonderful day :)

Comment: But how will the background change?

Comment: Only now I realize you intended that one could look through that hole. This would be quite a complicated thing to do, since you would have to build the entire room in 3D and that alone is a hefty task. But if you do, it's the same method for the whole: Place the room at its accurate position and let the tracked camera fly around it. Export this sequence and layer it with a mask on top of your footage. Like I said though, easier said than done.